# Обновление главной активности из дочерней

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу обновлять родительскую активность из дочерней. Т.е есть у меня две активности- главная (Родительская) и активность, которая открывается только после действий в главной (Дочерняя). По нажатию кнопки в дочерней активности мне надо обновить родительскую, как я могу это сделать или лучше реализовать постоянное обновление родительской активности?

Comment: а вы в родительскую как-то вернетесь после действия в дочерней, как понять что данные обновлены?

Comment: В родительской присутствует listview и его как раз и надо обновить после того, как его наполнение изменилось в дочерней

Comment: а какие данные влияют на обновление? можно просто через интент слать параметр обновления и всё

Comment: Возвращаюсь в родительскую кнопкой "назад" на телефоне

Comment: Я понимаю, что так можно, но вот возникли как раз проблемы с тем, как уловить нажатие на кнопку назад и запустить родительскую активность

Comment: добавил ответ, ознакомьтесь пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать `startActivityForResult()`.Переход на вторую активность:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

на второй активности когда что-то сделали для выбора фильтров возвращаем данные:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("editTextValue", "value_here")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

ну а в родительской активности ловим данные и фильтруем список:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             String strEditText = data.getStringExtra("editTextValue");
         }     
    }
}
```

[вот тут документация](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) где более подробно описан сам метод и [подобное обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android) где описаны разные варианты решения вашего вопроса

Comment: Я понял, спасибо огромное за ответ, а вот как можно в данной ситуации сделать постоянное обновление listview в родительской активности или это в данной ситуации будет лишним?

Comment: не очень понятно что значит постоянное обновление? вы перешли на активность - вернулись с данными обратно, снова перешли - снова вернулись)

Comment: Я имею в виду то под постоянным обновлением, что когда я перехожу к родительской активности, ее данные обновляются каждые n секунд или как-то так

Comment: мне кажется это будет лишним, у вас я так понимаю содержимое списка зависит от того что вы выбрали на второй активности, поэтому обновлять не изменяя при это данные мне кажется не совсем правильно)

Comment: Дело в том, что основные данные хранятся в базе и в дочерней активности я лишь удаляю один элемент из базы. И при этом в дальнейшем таких, как дочерняя активность планируется делать больше (это лишь пример). И не очень приятно для каждой данный код прописывать

Comment: ну вообще чтобы прям так не дублировать этот код я думаю имеет смысл как-то перейти на более легкий в плане производительности вариант с фрагментами, и так же стоит сделать класс в котором будет реализована прослойка с бд и тогда вопрос с фильтрацией будет решен попроще - при заходе на активность грузим то что есть после фильтрации и все)

Comment: Действительно то, что мне и надо! Спасибо большое, буду разбираться

Comment: Удачи вам в ваших начинаниях)